# Constant work-space algorithm for triangulating a set of points

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, triangulation

I'm researching this [paper](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rote/Papers/pdf/Constant-work-space+algorithms+for+geometric+problems.pdf) and attempting to implement some of the algorithms presented. I'm currently at the first algorithm, which presents a way to triangulate a set of points in a plane in quadratic time without using any work-space memory.

To save you from having to read everything about the algorithm, here's the main idea:

We traverse the points in a non-decreasing order of the x-coordinate. In each step we consider the current point *q_i*, and the point before *u*. We do a gift wrapping march from the point *u* and consider the edges we find along the way. For each edge we check **whether it's visible** from the point *q_i* and if it is we add a triangle made from *q_i* and that edge, we repeat that process until encountering the first non-visible edge. You can see the pseudocode for it on page 5.

The step that I'm not getting here is the one I've bolded, that is checking whether an edge is visible from the point *q_i*. How would you perform this check in linear time? Would you somehow have to iterate through all the triangles previously added and check whether any of their edges lies in between? How would this be done while maintaining the no extra memory restriction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side remark: I wonder what use such an algorithm could be. Quadratic time is poor performance when you have good O(n Log n) algorithms requiring constant additional space. Think that it's the representation of the triangulation itself that takes linear space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working counterclockwise from q<sub>i−1</sub> (which is always visible
from q<sub>i</sub>), the next hull edge a→b is visible if and only if
the triangle q<sub>i</sub>ab is clockwise, which you can check with a
cross product. Working clockwise, counterclockwise.